# Power Query Connection to mySQL running on Parallels - The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format

Tags: mysql, .net, parallels, powerquery, powerbi

Trying to connect to **mySQL** instance hosted on **AWS RDS via Power Query** and/or **Power BI Designer**. Getting the error

> "The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format"

in both applications.

I am running Office 365/Power Query & Power BI Designer on Windows 8.1 on a VM via Parallels.

I am able to connect to the database using the same credentials using Tableau or MySQL workbench or other applications, however Power Query/Power BI appears to have fallen over in the past couple of weeks after being fine for months before that.

Have tried reinstalling everything (*Office, Power Query, Windows, Drivers, MySQL NET connectors*) but no success.

Any ideas for to get the handshake to work?

Comment: What version of Power Query are you running?

Comment: Power Query Version: 2.20.3945.242 and Office version 15.0.4701.1002

Comment: Just updated to version 2.21.3974.242 - but still getting the same error.

Comment: Have you changed the MySQL .NET connector recently? This could explain why Tableau and MySQL Workbench can still connect because they do not use the .NET connector unlike Power Query and the Power BI Designer.

Comment: I agree the connector seems the likely culprit.  I've uninstalled and reinstalled both the most up to date connectors as well as older versions with no change unfortunately.  I'm running 64 bit windows and 64 bit office

Comment: Another user has a brand new computer, all new installs but basically same setup as mine, he also receives the same error.

Comment: Is it possible that some server-side configuration has changed? Perhaps you're now using a different version of the TLS protocol?

Comment: Problems resolved.  Thanks Curt & Alejrandro. Curt, something along those lines appears to have been the issue. AWS apparently changed their certificates and we hadn't rebooted our server instance in a while.  Rebooting our server to allow the AWS certificate changes to take hold corrected the handshake issue.

Answer (score 1):

Problems resolved. Thanks Curt & Alejrandro. Server-side changes appeared to have been the issue. AWS apparently changed their certificates and we hadn't rebooted our server instance in a while. Rebooting our server to allow the AWS certificate changes to take hold corrected the handshake issue.

Lukasz, ODBC source did work the whole time, but it was more a matter of not wanting to rebuild the model I'd built using the MySQL connector and I wasn't confident enough with M to manually change the source to ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

Power BI Designer and Power Query now support ODBC data sources.
https://support.powerbi.com/knowledgebase/articles/471643-data-sources-in-power-bi-designer

Perhaps that would work on your system?  Could you let me know if it resolves the issue? Won't be as good as the .Net connector, but it probably will get you going.

HTH, 
-Lukasz

- http://dev.powerbi.com
- http://blogs.msdn.com/powerbidev
- Make a feature request: https://support.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi
- Sign up for Power BI: http://www.powerbi.com